# Execute gnome-terminal on a remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, ubuntu-server

I have an Ubuntu 16 server deployed on a remote machine. I am connecting via `ssh` and what I want to accomplish is to open a new terminal using the `gnome-terminal` command. I want to to do this because I have a python script that executes this command and needs a second terminal for a process it spawns. The error message I get is

`Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:`

Is there any way around this?